# How to deal with "Unhandled 'error' event" error - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to get hands on Node.js. Here is the very simple code I was playing with

```js
var http = require('http');
http.get('www.google.com', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

I got the following error upon running this code

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

upon reading the error output, I added two more lines of code to handle error event like below

```js
var http = require('http');
http.get('www.google.com', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

but the same error message was still persisting, where am I messing it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use a URL and not a domain name in [`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) unless you specify `options` as an object:

> `options` can be an object or a string. If `options` is a string, it is automatically parsed with `url.parse()`.

Compare:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://www.google.com/', function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

With:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get({host:'www.google.com'}, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Both of those work.

---

Note I thought that it was a network issue at first but actually what happened the default for `host` in the options is `localhost` so that when it failed to parse the string and was left with the default options. As if the code had been:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get({}, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```